# python twitter 404

Tags: python, api, twitter, python-twitter

I'm trying to use twitter-python to connect to twitter's API, and I keep getting this pesky 404 error!

## Code is below:

```
import sys
import twitter
def main():
  api = twitter.Api()
  statuses = api.GetPublicTimeline()
  print [s.user.name for s in statuses]
```

---

It should come back with the names of people who've posted status updates on the public timeline, but I get this traceback instead.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "new.py", line 10, in main
    statuses = api.GetPublicTimeline()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/twitter.py", line 1319, in GetPublicTimeline
    json = self._FetchUrl(url,  parameters=parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/twitter.py", line 2030, in _FetchUrl
    url_data = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

If I try to authenticate, all of my requests come back as 401.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

on https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ they say:

*The python-twitter library now only supports oAuth authentication as the Twitter devs have indicated that oAuth is the only method that will be supported moving forward.*

> > > api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
> > >       consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token', access_token_secret='access_token_secret')

Is that relevant to your problem ?

Comment: It might be.  I don't know anything about oAuth, so I'll do some research on that and see what I come up with.

Comment: I'm not definite but Twitter have made some changes recently and it may that a lot of example code ``out there`` is out of date and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is one of the better APIs when it comes to making the oAuth process painless for developers. If you log in to Twitter and go to the developer dashboard at https://dev.twitter.com/apps, you can register a new application (or configure your existing apps).

Viewing the application details will give you an "oAuth Tool" tab, where you'll find all the relevant oAuth values for that app: Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token, and Access Token Secret.

If you're creating an application that will always authenticate with Twitter as the same user, you can simply hard-code these values into your code or store them in a config file somewhere. If your application needs to authenticate with Twitter on behalf of multiple users (eg, so that it can post statuses on behalf of a user), then you'll need to go through the oAuth dance which is described at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization.